# How do I know who is following me on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr, followers

In actual fact it is likely that no-one is following me, but I'm unable to figure out if I have zero followers or not as I can't seem to find any links to the list of my followers.

Where does the list appear if I have any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to go to your dashboard and  visit the Followers page. That will show other users that are following your blog.

[From the Tumblr help page](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/dashboard)

> #### Following and Followers
>
> The [Following](http://www.tumblr.com/following) page shows blogs
>   that **you** are following. Posts from
>   these blogs will appear in real-time
>   on your [Dashboard](http://www.tumblr.com/dashboard).
>
> The [Followers](http://www.tumblr.com/followers) page shows other
>   users that are **following your
>   blog.**
>
> You can follow any Tumblr blog you
>   visit by clicking the **Follow** icon
>   in the top right corner of the page.
>   Or, you can enter it manually on your
>   [Following](http://www.tumblr.com/following) page.

Comment: Great - thanks. I have 0 followers. Interesting that this is completely hidden when this is the case.

Comment: @thesaundi You will receive an email when your follower count changes. Also the count will appear on the right side between posts and drafts.

Answer (score 1):

You can track who follows and unfollows you with TumQuit. Automatically follow or unfollow those who do the same to you and receive daily or weekly email alters.

Disclaimer: Affiliated to TurnQuit

Comment: Please state your affiliation with the service, otherwise the answer will be considered spam. Thanks!

Comment: It's just a website that answers the question.

Comment: _However, you **must** disclose your affiliation in your answers._ See [this FAQ question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).